# Perform an action after a document in viewed on desktop

Tags: javafx

I am viewing an excel on desktop from my application using

```
MainClass.getHostServicesUpg().showDocument("UploadData.xls");
```

I want to view another javafx stage once this file is open(or best when the file is closed by the user). Is there anyway I can monitor the file opening closing to view my next stage?

Comment: Do you have access to the directory where the file is? When the application creates a lock file, you could use a `WatchService` that informs you when a file was created or deleted.

Comment: Yes I have the access. The file will be present on the local. Can you please elaborate on how to use `WatchService` and how will file creation or deletion info help me know when to show the stage?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) you can implement the WatchService to see if some sort of a look file was created. If that is the case you can open your stage. And if you notice the lock file was deleted you close your stage. This must be checked periodically since the WatchKey doesn't wait for events by the WatchService.

If you want i can try to create a small understandable example but that would take a while.

Comment: I followed the tutorial to implement WatchService but it never returned me anything.. Well I need to understand the functionality of the code. I'll get back to you once I understand it and find any difficulty. Or if have an easy way to make it clear then please share your knowledge.